MSSQL Server connection goes to sleeping state and blocking another queries
I am encountering an issue with a sleeping connection in MSSQL production server. My application is a multi-tenant application that connects to 6 databases and has 30 Tomcat instances. I have used the following libraries:

JDK: Azul 11.0.12.0.101
Apache Tomcat/9.0.54
Mssql Driver Version 12.8.0.jre11
HikariCP Version 5.1.0 (latest)

Hikari cp config

"maxLifetime": 1320000,
"idleTimeout": 238000,
"connectionTimeout": 30000,
"minimumIdle": 5,
"maximumPoolSize": 10,
"keepaliveTime": 30000,
"connectionTestQuery": "IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRAN", // added this test query, but still not working.
"leakDetectionThreshold": 60000
"dataSource.ConnectRetryCount": 5,
"dataSource.ConnectRetryInterval": 5,
"dataSource.queryTimeout": 1200,
"dataSource.cancelQueryTimeout": 300,
"dataSource.lockTimeout": 1500000,
"dataSource.socketTimeout": 1500000,

I have attempted to adjust the above Hikari pool configuration multiple times, but I am still receiving the sleeping connection issue, which is causing other queries to become blocked. When checking sp_whoisactive in the MSSQL server, I can see that sessions are in sleeping states for hours. It appears that HikariCP is not closing connections properly.
During my investigation of the HikariCP code, I discovered that in the method PoolBase.quietlyCloseConnection, it attempts to close connections. However, I found that it sets the NetworkTimeout hardcoded to 15 seconds. This leads me to question whether this shorter timeout is causing the connections to not be closed properly.
Can you provide any assistance? Thank you in advance.
Note: There is an Azure gateway between the application and database.

What do you mean with other queries to become blocked? Are new queries not starting or what? How does the code looks that uses this "pool"?

@siggemannen This means that while executing sp_whoisactive, I can detect other queries for the same database, but their status is displayed as suspended. Additionally, the session ID of the main sleeping query is shown as the blocked session for those suspended queries.

That's something else, meaning someone is not releasing it's work. What does: dbcc opentran shows?

It shows some Oldest active transaction, checking on this

It's probably unrelated but: "connectionTestQuery": "IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRAN" is a bad query to use, since it changes things. SELECT 1 is standard me thinks
